# Modify session cookie expiry and session timeout for a CakePHP session

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, session-timeout

I'm struggling to accomplish the following:
Alter the user's session cookie expiry date based on the user's type.

I have a CakePHP web application wherein I have created my authentication component (instead of CakePHP's Auth) using CakePHP sessions. I've configured CakePHP to handle sessions using the database.

Here are the relevant configuration settings that I have in my config.php:

```
Configure::write('Session.save', 'database');
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '36');
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

How do I extend the session cookie expiry date AND update the value in the **"expires"** column in the **"sessions"** table?

Comment: maybe this can help: 'high'   Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 10; 'medium' Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 100; 'low'    Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 300;

Comment: This may help too: http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/02/more-persistent-sessions-in-cake2-x/

Answer (score 6):

Go in app/config/core.php

In this file search for,

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
```

Session time out time (in seconds), by default it is 120 seconds. You can edit it here as required.
Now the actual timeout duration depends on,

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');

if 'high' then Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 10, 
if 'medium' then Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 100, 
if 'low'    Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 300
```

So by combination of Session.timeout and Security.level you can get the desired session timeout

Comment: can this be configures on the fly ? say some user with a greater expiry time than others?

Answer (score 4):

Find this: `app/config/core.php`

Change this line to your desired value in minutes:
`Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');`

(Since CakePHP 2.3.0 `Security.level` is no longer used.
Changelog: http://cakephp.org/changelogs/2.3.0)