# Configuration setting 'Security.level' in CakePHP 2.x still used?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.2

I can't find any reference to the `Security.level` configuration setting from Cake 1.3 in the [CakePHP 2.2 manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html).

I also can't find any reference to this setting in the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/migrating-from-cakephp-1-2-to-1-3.html).

This setting had a big impact on the session timer in Cake 1.3.

> **Security.level**
>
> > The level of CakePHP security. The session timeout time defined in ‘Session.timeout’ is multiplied according to the settings here.
> >
> > 'high' = x 10 'medium' = x 100 'low' = x 300 'high' and 'medium' also enable session.referer_check

Has this setting in the `config.php` of an application been removed in CakePHP 2.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No the setting has not been removed

It still exists in [core.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#L181)

```
/**
 * The level of CakePHP security.
 */
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

### But...

It's not used in 2.x.

The only reference to this setting is in [Security::inactiveMins](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L36) - which isn't called by anything else. Therefore, while there is still an artefact of this setting left over in 2.x, the intention of this setting has been removed and hence it's not in the 2.x docs.

Comment: So, why don't you, as a collaborator, mention this in CakePHP documentaion? The support for CakePHP 1.3 is ending or ended and we are migrating from it.

Comment: It should be mentioned [in the migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html), it'll be an oversight that it's not there - as you would like the docs to mention this why don't you, as anyone can, click "Improve this Doc" instead of commanding that I do it =).

Answer (score 3):

With CakePHP 2.3 `Security.level` was removed from `core.php`.

Session timeout is set by this setting:

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
```

Also: [Modify session cookie expiry and session timeout for a CakePHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292890/modify-session-cookie-expiry-and-session-timeout-for-a-cakephp-session/22125253#22125253)