# Cakephp session timeout does not affect session expiration

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

This questions did not solve my problem
[Session timeout doesn't work + cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673638/session-timeout-doesnt-work-cakephp)

[Modify session cookie expiry and session timeout for a CakePHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292890/modify-session-cookie-expiry-and-session-timeout-for-a-cakephp-session/)

[CakePHP Session Timeout on Inactivity only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470018/cakephp-session-timeout-on-inactivity-only)

I wanted to test if session timeouts work fine, I decided to test it and to not wait long I set these values in my core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 1,
    'cookieTimeout' => 1440
));
```

according to documentation
`Session.timeout - The number of minutes before CakePHP’s session handler expires the session`

So, to test it, I open new incognito window, login, then wait for more than 1 minute and refresh the page, what I expect is that the user should be logged out, but it is not. I do not have any ajax requests. Why the user is not being logged out ? If I am doing smth wrong, then how to handle this situation, I mean I want to set the user to be logged out after `x` minutes of inactivity.

I am using cake v2.5.3

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `cookieTimeout` to 1 as well?  And what about trying `'autoRegenerate' => false`

Comment: @Dave, tried, no difference, thanks